# FIFO Queue linked list implementation

Tags: c++

Here is code in which I am trying to implement a queue using linked list:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
template <class Item>
class Queue{

public:
    struct  node{
      Item item;node *next;
      node (Item x){
        item=x; next=0;
      }
    };
    typedef node* link;
    link  head, tail;

public:
    Queue(int){  head=0;}
    int empty() const {   return head==0; }
    void put(Item x){

        node* t=tail;
        tail=new node(x);
        if (head==0) head=tail;
        else   t->next=tail;
    }
    Item get(){  

        Item v=head->item;link t=head->next;
        delete head; head=tail return v;
    }

    };

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

but I have problems with pointers. For example, when I write `Item v = head->` it should   show me option to choose item but it does not show. Also in other place of code after -> this sign code does not give me possibility to choose item or next. Please help.

Comment: Can you post the exact problem you're having, including as appropriate wrong output, error messages, and desired output. Also please use sentences, your question is difficult to read.

Comment: Considering `it should show me option to choose`: Do you want your IDE (your editor) to show up a list of `head`s members? Or something else?

Comment: yes members  but it does not show me

Comment: Ok, but then it is not a problem of `FIFO Queue linked list implementation` but a problem with your editor. What editor are you using?

Comment: I haven't been using VS for quite a time, but I know that its IntelliSense doesnt work sometimes. So try googling "visual studio 2010 intellisense not working" or something similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ON: The -> operator can be overloaded so the development environment cannot be sure what to do with it. You can do the following (temporarily or permanently) if you really want to have auto-completion.

```
// IMPORTANT. Make sure "head" is not null before you do it!
Node &headNode(*head); // Create a reference 
headNode.next = tail; // Use TAB or CTRL+SPACE or whatever here after dot
```

OFF: I reviewed your code and made some corrections

```
template <class Item>
class Queue {
public:
        Queue()
        : head(0)
        , tail(0)
        { }
        bool empty() const { return head==0; }
        void put(const Item& x)
        {
                Node* t = tail;
                tail = new Node(x);
                if (head==0)
                        head = tail;
                else
                        t->next = tail;
        }
        Item get()
        {
                Item v = head->item;
                Link t = head->next;
                delete head;
                head = t;
                if(head==0)
                        tail = 0;
                return v;
        }
private:
        struct Node {
                Item item;
                Node *next;
                Node(const Item& x)
                : item(x)
                , next(0)
                {}
        };
        typedef Node* Link;
        Link head,tail;
};
```

- Removed `int` typed nameless parameter from `Queue` constructor
- Renamed `node` to `Node` and `link` to `Link` because `Item` is `Item`, not `item`. Just to make it somewhat standardized
- Initializing `tail` at the constructor of `Queue`.
- Using initializer list instead of code where possible.
- Fixing `Queue::get()`, setting `tail` to zero if the queue become empty.
- Using constant reference in parameter lists of `Queue::put()` and `Queue::Node::Node()`
- `Node`, `Link`, `head` and `tail` is private from now.
- `Queue::empty()` returns `bool` instead of `int` from now.

Answer (score 3):

You would probably be better off reusing an existing container.

The STL explicitly contains, for example, a `queue` Container Adapter (based on `deque` by default, which is the most efficient choice).

If you don't need polymorphic behavior, a `std::queue<Item>` is what you're looking for, it's both extremely efficient (more than your custom list-based queue) and you will avoid memory management issues.

If you need polymorphic behavior, then use a `std::queue< std::unique_ptr<Item> >`.

Comment: "Don't reinvent the wheel, unless you plan to learn more about wheels."

Comment: I think you're over-engineering the answer. He just has problems with his editor's automatic completion feature.

Comment: @cevalek: I guess so too, it wasn't clear before the comments though. What's amusing is that I still get upvotes for this, so I guess I wasn't the only one who didn't pick up the real issue.